# How does one let a for-loop add a number to the end of a variable name

Tags: python, python-3.x

So basically I'm trying to build a calculator using Python. I understand this might not be the most optimal, but I love Python and wanted a challenge. I'm currently trying to figure out a way to make an "infinite" amount of numbers and operators possible, so I would like to know whether it is possible for example to add a number after variable `n` making `n1`, `n2`, `n3` and a number after operator `op` making `op1`, `op2`, `op3` etc.

If there are better ways to do that, that'd be great, as I'm still relatively new when it comes to Python.

Comment: It looks like you want variable names that your program creates dynamically at runtime. The normal way to do that in Python is to use a dict. Instead of trying to create variable `myvar123`, create a dict `myvar` and then do `myvar[123] = ...` .

Answer (score 1):

> If there are better ways to do that that'd be great as I'm still relatively new when it comes to python.

Yes. Lists. Or dicts, but probably lists. Possibly `deque` (double-ended queue) depending on the exact way you want to use it (it's quite inefficient to add or remove items from the front of a normal `list`, especially as the size of the list increases). Wanting to create *variable names* dynamically is a huge red flag.

> I'm currently trying to figure out away to make an "infinite" amount

Look up iterators and generators, as well as itertools. These are tools to lazily build and compose infinite sequences of things.

Though I don't quite get why you'd want that for a calculator, unless you want to generate a stream of data and operations for testing? In which case I'd suggest taking a gander at [hypothesis](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Answer (score 1):

## What you asked for (NB: *not* what you need)

> so I would like to know whether it is possible for example to add a number after variable n making n1, n2, n3 and a number after operator op making op1, op2, op3 etc.

By inserting into the dictionary of global variables returned by `globals()`, you can actually *create* global variables, thereby allowing you to use string manipulation for their names:

```
globals_dict = globals()

for i in range(50):
    # As an example, let's put i squared into variable n{i},
    # i.e., 0 squared (= 0) into n0, 1 squared (= 1)  into n1,
    # 2 squared (= 4) into n2, etc.
    globals_dict[f"n{i}"] = i**2

assert n11 == 121  # Check that n11 is actually 11 squared, i.e., 121.
```

In some implementations of Python, this even works for the dictionary of local variables returned by `locals()` for creating local variables, but other than with `globals()` that behavior is unspecified and should not be relied on.

For using these variables without hard-coding their names you'd have to access `globals()` or `globals_dict`  again, **which is entirely impractical**.

## What you actually need

There's a pythonic (i.e., idiomatic in Python) way to put multiple values into a single variable: **Collection types.** The most general purpose (and thus most commonly used) ones are built into the language itself:

- [dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict)
- [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list)
- [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set)
- [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple)

More collection types are available in the [standard library module `collections`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html).

If you are unsure how to use the built-in collections, going through the [Python tutorial in the official Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) would probably be a good idea.